# How to switch apache virtualhost from `http` to `https` through apache conf file?

Tags: apache

My Apache 2.4 conf file as below:

```
Listen 80
Listen 443 https

NameVirtualHost *:443
#
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
DocumentRoot "/home/websites/example/www"
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/path/to/www.example.com.cert"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/path/to/www.example.com.key"
# HSTS (mod_headers is required) (63072000 seconds = 2years)
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000;includeSubDomains;"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com$1 [NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

My thought:
As `<VirtualHost *:443>`, then any setting within `<VirtualHost` is effective only when apache listen port `443`,then `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on` will never become true,then `http://` will not switch to `https://`.
Then,how to write Apache conf file to make `virtualhost *:443` switch `http://` to `https://`?

Comment: @symcbean,actually, I just want to switch `http://` to `https://`

Comment: I wrote that then started writing a better response below - hence deleting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title of your question is an oxymoron - do you want the same behaviour on port 80 as 443? Do you want to send all your port 80 traffic to port 443? Since a comment in your code mentions HSTS, I will assume the latter.

Declare a default host for port 80, and redirect all the traffic in that virtual host. I would strongly recommend that you use a 302 rather than a 301 redirect, at least until your config is working the way you want.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin admin@example.com
 DocumentRoot "/home/websites/example/EMPTYDIR"
 ServerName example.com

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

(BTW, using your default to handle an explicitly named virtual host is a bit untidy).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! At first, I think switch to `https` just need one line script.I am newbie,pls feel free to talk,any improvement for tidy?